# C# What is the "object sender" of Form?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have a form and there is button and label. I have "Click" event handler, Button and Form both have same Click event handler. I want to make If "sender" is from Button print: Hello From Button and if "sender" is from Form print: Hello World. I know we can do it it if else but what is the name of form? When i take form name from properties it generates error and says it is Type.

```
public partial class simpleEventExample : Form
{        

    public simpleEventExample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void firstButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if (sender == firstButton )
        {
            displayLabel.Text = "Hello From Button";

        }
        if (sender == simpleEventExample )  ***//(Error says it is type)***
        {
            displayLabel.Text = "Hello World";
        }

    }

}
```

Look at picture name is simple
[image]

Comment: Why not cast the sender and then use the `Name` property? `sender` is an object, you need to cast it to the type you need...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ It doesnt work as well.

Comment: `if (sender is firstButton) { somthing... } else { something }`... there's many ways to do this. According to your post, how about you show what the `Click` event is... that shows you wiring the events up to this event..

Comment: simpleEventExample is your form class: `public class simpleEventExample : Form`, hence the error. The sender is the Button itself which triggered the event. In this case, it must be `firstButton`

Comment: If you want to check an event is triggered by your form, please check `if sender == this;` as @darksquirrel42 suggested

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I say it in above. I know we can do it with if else. But i need its name.

Comment: @MahmoodGaribov then try and cast it... and get the name property... I've said this already. `if(sender is Button btn && btn.Name == "someName"){dosomething}` then you can do an `elseif` to check what ever other types you want and props...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to check against `this` ... not `simpleEventExample`

```
public partial class simpleEventExample : Form
{        

    public simpleEventExample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void firstButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if (sender == firstButton )
        {
            displayLabel.Text = "Hello From Button";

        }
        if (sender == this )  // this means the object whos member the current function is... in other words.. your form ... 
        {
            displayLabel.Text = "Hello World";
        }
        else if ((sender as simpleEventExample)?.Name == "simpleEventExample")  // if you REALLY need to check the name...  
        {
            displayLabel.Text = "Hello World";
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Since this answer was accepted already, can the OP @Mahmood Garibov explain how this get's the controls name according to their comment above: `I say it in above. I know we can do it with if else. But i need its name`.

Comment: Thanks, but OP is changing their requirements. It makes answering a question hard... They accepted before ever mentioning they need it by name...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ ... i see... but OP is clearly new here and obviously not so fluent in english so ... i'd say let's not be that strict...

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your error would be to do this:

```
if (sender == this)
```

Or this:

```
if (sender is simpleEventExample)
//if (sender is Form) // This is also okay.
```

...and the whole thing could become:

```
if (sender is Button )
{
    displayLabel.Text = "Hello From Button";
}

if (sender is simpleEventExample )
{
    displayLabel.Text = "Hello World";
}
```

But I would advise you to not reuse event handlers as a general rule, especially between dissimilar controls.

Comment: `But I would advise you to not reuse event handlers as a general rule` there's nothing wrong with reusing events....

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ No, not until you need to do something useful with them. A `Button` click is generally a different interaction than a `Form` click.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I'm not sure why you think it's a label click... Anyway, it's just friendly advice for OP, you may do whatever you like of course.

Answer (score -1):

Do like below.

```
public partial class simpleEventExample : Form
{        

    public simpleEventExample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void firstButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if (sender is Button)
        {
            displayLabel.Text = "Hello From Button";
        }
        else
        {
            displayLabel.Text = "Hello World";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Read the question fully then answer. I know we can do it with if else but i need its name